# Text content of div set by JS wont break to new line

Tags: javascript, html

i have some div created with JS and  `mydiv.textContent="blahblahblahblahblahblah";`
despite the fact mydiv have width set to 100px, string of text assigned to div keeps on going in one line and wont drop to other text. i am confused

Comment: There is no space in your string. HTML/CSS won't break up words by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your css use

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: That breaks words, as the name says, and should not be used unless the content is freely breakable.

Comment: Very good point. In this case however it seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a string breakable into two lines and it contains no spaces, you need to insert suitable control characters or HTML tags that allow acceptable breaks, or maybe use automatic hyphenation. So this really depends on the kind of content you have; see my [page on word breaks](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) in HTML.

If the content is literally `"blahblahblahblahblahblah"` as a JavaScript string, make it `"blah\xadblah\xadblah\xadblah\xadblah\xadblah"`. The notation `\xad` stands for U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN, which is treated as an invisible hyphenation hint.

Comment: Does this work as is, or do you have to use CSS to specify hyphen breaking?

Comment: @Asad, it works as is and does not require any CSS. It is an alternative to using automatic hyphenation (which is possible, but still rather incompletely implemented).